# How to add multiple subreport in a master report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to add multiple sub report in a master report. I have add 3 sub report successfully but when i add 4th number sub report it gone next page the number of 3 and 4 sub report not displaying data. please help me how can i add multiple sub report in a master report?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple subreports in a master report and coming to your question **when i add 4th number sub report it gone next page** it depends on where you are placing the 4th sub report and how much space first 3 subreports occupying. If first 3 sub reports occupying first page then naturally 4th subreport will go to next page.

**If this is not your query then provide more info in your question**

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the proper space to fit the subreports. You can try File-->Page Setup and reduce the margins or File-->Printer Setup and change to Landscape to see if that gives you more room.